# Profile 2 Module Shows normal user Registration form elements on every form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, user-registration

We create Different Registration form for some specific users using **PROFILE2 Module**

But normal user registration form element appearing on every user registration form.

like username >> email >> newsletter Subscription and Full name

These fields are not manageable From Profile 2 setting page on Admin section

Can any one help me regarding this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manage this fields in profile type and make it as hidden from admin panel